# Is there any way to enable detailed tracing of http2 requests and responses in Go?

Tags: go

Is there any way to enable detailed tracing of http2 requests and responses in GO?

I would like to be able to log connection attempts, timeouts, and transmission of requests so that I can diagnose production problems after the fact.

Stracing is fine during development, but it not useful for determining the details of problems after they occur.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `GODEBUG=http2debug=1` or `GODEBUG=http2debug=2` environment variable.

Example:

```
 env GODEBUG=http2debug=2 go run something.go
```

source: http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: The data frames are truncated which is what I am trying to inspect, anyone know a way to see the read and write contents in full?

Comment: The data frames are truncated which is what I am trying to inspect, anyone know a way to see the read and write contents in full?
In strace you would use -s to change the string truncation.